# Why does Jest fail the test when checking for a valid instance of Promise?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, instanceof

I'm using Jest 20.0.3, and the test is simple:

```
it('should return a Promise', () => {
  expect(new Promise(r => r())).toBeInstanceOf(Promise);
});
```

and it fails with

```
● should return a Promise

  expect(value).toBeInstanceOf(constructor)

  Expected value to be an instance of:
    "Promise"
  Received:
    {"fulfillmentValue": undefined, "isFulfilled": false, "isRejected": false, "rejectionReason": undefined}
  Constructor:
    "Promise"
```

At the same time, if I test for instance of Object, it works:

```
it('should return an Object', () => {
  expect(new Object()).toBeInstanceOf(Object); // <- this one passes
});
```

I tried to compare instance's constructor with Promise object but it still doesn't work. I tried use `expect(•).toHaveProperty` and check whether the returned object has "then" and "catch" properties, but it seems to be not, so that test failed as well.

What am I doing wrong? How can I test a function for its returned value that has to be in instance of Promise?

Comment: In JS .instanceOf is pretty shady. I don't know the exact implementation behind Jest assertion. From what I see you don't have instance of Promise in the received value - it's plain object with some props. It may be returned from the new Promise(), but nothing about it screams Promise to the JIT. You can try to test with getPrototypeOf, or check if you are compiling to version of ES that doesn't support promises and this is what causes the error.