# Weird Promise behavior in Jest when tests rely on the Firestore emulator

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, promise, jestjs

While using the Google Cloud's Firestore Emulator, I'm calling the following method:

```
global.db.runTransaction(async () => 100)
```

This dummy call works when executed using `node`, but fails when executed using `jest` inside a `test` function. When running it from Jest, the `runTransaction` method throws:

> Error: You must return a Promise in your transaction()-callback.

referencing [node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/transaction.js:362:27](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/ce9abfd8cd65d0d2be4dd7f6a56fb679a100296a/dev/src/transaction.ts#L479)

That file has the following snippet of code, which is causing the failure:

```
async runTransaction(updateFunction, options) {
  // ...
  const promise = updateFunction(this);
  if (!(promise instanceof Promise)) {
    throw new Error('You must return a Promise in your transaction()-callback.');
  }
  // ...
}
```

In other words, when running in Jest, the library considers `async () => 100` function not to return a promise.

I changed the library code to add some debug messages:

```
async runTransaction(updateFunction, options) {
  // ...
  const promise = updateFunction(this);
  if (!(promise instanceof Promise)) {
    // *** Added these debug messages ***
    console.log(updateFunction);
    console.log(promise);
    console.log(promise instanceof Promise);

    throw new Error('You must return a Promise in your transaction()-callback.');
  }
  // ...
}
```

And I am getting the following:

```
[AsyncFunction (anonymous)]
Promise { 100 }
false
```

To complicate matters, this test passes as expected within `jest`:

```
test('promise', () => {
  const fn = async () => 100;
  const res = fn();
  expect(res instanceof Promise).toEqual(true);
}
```

I'm a bit at a loss here as to why executing this library code with Jest fails compared to Node, while executing a similar statement with Jest in the code snippet just above succeeds.

Any suggestions on how to approach this head-scratcher?

**EDIT**

Initializing a local `db` variable instead of `global.db` solves the issue.

Originally, I had the `global.db` set in `jest.config.js` like so:

```
module.exports = async () => {
  const Firestore = require("@google-cloud/firestore");
  global.db = new Firestore({ projectId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT });

  return {}
}
```

The application code works by relying on `global.db` that is set through an initialization file, and I wanted to mimic this for the tests.

I guess the question is, then, how should one go about initializing a global db variable that can be used in all tests?

**ANSWER**

Ended up creating a `setup.js` file and loaded it with `setupFilesAfterEnv` per [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--setupfilesafterenv-path1--pathn). Content:

```
const Firestore = require("@google-cloud/firestore/build/src");
global.db = new Firestore({ projectId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT });
```

Now things are working properly. Other solutions, such as using the `globals` entry in the object exported in `jest.config.js` (not shown in code snippets above) didn't work as per [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globals-object) the values must be JSON-serializable, which is not the case for Firestore.

Comment: Have you tried db.runTransaction(async () => Promise.resolve(100))

Comment: Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043619/why-does-jest-fail-the-test-when-checking-for-a-valid-instance-of-promise
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746304/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-promise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest's expect(value).toBeInstanceOf(Class) fails for expect(util.promisify(...)()).toBeInstanceOf(Promise) and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029714/jests-expectvalue-tobeinstanceofclass-fails-for-expectutil-promisify)

Comment: @KostasMinaidis tried both `async () => Promise.resolve(100)` and `() => new Promise((res, rej) => res(10))` and getting same behavior.

Comment: @SuperStormer OP is not on his own testing for a `Promise` (with Jest). It's Googles Firestore that fails the test.

Comment: @SuperStormer indeed @Andreas is correct - the failure happens inside library code, not a Jest `expect` function. I cannot alter the way that the library code performs the Promise type check. Nevertheless, `expect((async () => 100)() instanceof Promise).toEqual(true)` works, so I'm at a loss as to why a similar statement inside the library code fails, even with Jest.

Comment: @Andreas The problem is the same: jest is messing with the globals.